# Smoothing with lowess

Tags: r, matlab, smoothing

I'm trying to convert a matlab script to R, and am having some trouble with smoothing.

The matlab code I want to convert is the following:

```
for i = 1:size(spike_sum,2)
        smooth_sum(1:Ne,i)=smooth(double(spike_sum(1:Ne,i)),spanNe,'lowess');
end

for i = 1:Ne
        smoother_sum(i,:)=smooth(double(smooth_sum(i,:)),spanT,'lowess');
end
```

where spike_sum is a matrix that is Ne x 4000.  I want to first smooth in Dim 1, with span spanNe, and do that for all 4000 slices.  Then, I want to smooth in Dim 2 with span spanT, and do that for all Ne slices.

I've looked at the lowess function in R, but it seems like it takes in 2 dimensions as lowess(x,y,span,iter,delta).  So to get the results of the code above in R, would I just take a slice of the matrix for y and replicate a constant value for x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although the answer provided by joran did not work as intended, and joran spent quite a bit of time trying to debug it, which I appreciate, ultimately I was unable to get that solution to work, and I don't really know why, but it was not producing results comparable to the matlab code.  After messing around I found out this solution (which might not be optimal, but works as expected)

```
loesscontrol=loess.control(surface="interpolate", statistics="approximate", trace.hat="exact", iterations=1)
spanNe=100/Ne
spanT=50/nsteps
spanNi=30/Ni

for (i in 1:nsteps){
        x<-1:Ne
        y<-spike_sum[1:Ne,i]
        smoothingNe<-loess.smooth(x, y, span=spanNe, degree=1, family="gaussian", evaluation=Ne)
        smooth_sumNe[1:Ne,i]<-smoothingNe$y
}

for (i in 1:Ne){
        x<-1:nsteps
        y<-smooth_sumNe[i,1:nsteps]
        smoothingT<-loess.smooth(x, y, span=spanT, degree=1, control=loesscontrol, family="gaussian", evaluation=nsteps)
        smoother_sumNe[i,1:nsteps]<-smoothingT$y        
}
```

I want to mention that one of the keys here was to set evaluation=Ne in the first smoothing, because otherwise the result was null.  I don't know why that was, but perhaps because the data was sparse and highly discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

My Matlab is quite rusty, but if I've understood you correctly, you probably want to pass the sequence `1:Ne` or `1:4000` for the `x` argument to `lowess`, as that is meant to be the x coordinates of the points your are smoothing. This assumes that you are assuming your points are indeed equally spaced.

Something like this would work:

```
#Example matrix
M <- matrix(runif(1600),40,40)

#Smooth rows; transpose when smoothing over rows
M1 <- t(apply(M,1,FUN = function(x){lowess(1:length(x),x)$y}))

#Smooth columns; but don't transpose; fills by column already
M2 <- apply(M1,2,FUN = function(x){lowess(1:length(x),x)$y})
```

I didn't include the different spans, but you can add those details in yourself.

*Edit*

Ah, but if you're looking for speed, you should probably be using `loess.smooth` directly. `loess` uses a formula interface, so you'll want to call `loess.smooth` directly. It's defaults are different than `lowess`, though, so be careful. Swapping that function in cut the running time for me by almost 1/4.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to test it out but this out but a couple of things.  First, M2 would be based on M1, not M, since I want to smooth the already smoothed data a second time, but this time in the other dimension.  I went ahead and changed that.  Second, this seems to flip the dimensions of the first matrix, so that the next two matrices are NxM instead of MxN.  I don't know any R (I use matlab generally) so I'm not sure what sets that, in matlab it could simply be fixed with the ' operator

Comment: You transpose matrices in R using `t()`. I was mostly trying to give you the raw ingredients of a solution, since as I said, my Matlab is really rusty so I'm not going to be great at translating. I'll edit this to address your notes.

Comment: Also, this seems to be about twice as slow as the equivalent matlab code (30 seconds vs 1 minute) which is kind of a bummer since I need to run this several thousand times a day.  I wonder why that is.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't complaning, was just having trouble testing it out to verify the solution.  Thanks, i'll try it again.

Comment: @CHP See my edit; I should have mentioned that `lowess` is a little be 'old' in R. Most people use `loess` now (or in your case `loess.smooth` to get the same output at `lowess`). It should be quite a bit faster.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot in a bit.  I tried the old method and did not get the expected result.  The data did not appear smooth in any way (though it did appear altered).  I'll check out the new methods and see, and maybe I'm doing the spans wrong or something as they seem to be different than matlab.

Comment: @CHP Well, I can assure that smoothing is happening. ;) But I can't help you troubleshoot that without examples that illustrate what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Is it possible to upload images here?  If not it's hard to explain, but basically spike_sum is a raster plot of Ne neurons across time, so that at any given time window, the number of times a neuron fires is the value of spike_sum.  I want to smooth that across time and neuron space individually.  The matlab code does this and the resulting plot retains the same characteristics but is smoothed.  The R code returns something that looks just like another unsmoothed raster plot but it looks different.  Like this:  http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/10/9/910/F2.medium.gif if you can see it

Comment: If that wasn't clear, spike_sum is like A in the figure, I want to produce the data to plot something like B, which is smoothed version of A

Comment: @CHP let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4209/discussion-between-joran-and-chp)